# How do I insert data into sections with dividers in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I have a sheet which is importing data from another sheet using `importrange`. I've formatted the sheet so that between different "sections", there is a solid blue divider. How do I place data into those sections and "expand" the sections (by adding another row above the divider).

What I would like it to look like

[image: What I want the imported data to be formatted like]

But say if I add another element in the originial sheet and import the data, this is what it would look like:

[image]

However, I want it to instead move the blue line down instead of putting the data on the blue line so that it looks like this:

[image]

The divider row will always be fully blank.

Comment: Can you please show the code and/or post a google sheet link you are already using to produce your current example. You can use importrange on the a different sheet in the same workbook to simplify your example.

Comment: [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Why not just use conditional formatting to blue the blank line?

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't realise you could check if whole lines were blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in column A and B you would just use conditional formatting to make the blank line blue. Something like this could be done:

```
Format -> Conditional Formatting

Apply to Range: A1:B

Custom Formula: =($A1&$B1)=""

Apply the color blue
```

If you share more code to make this problem more specific I can modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks that worked, is there a way to merge the line as well?

Comment: @JadenJin I'm not aware of a way to do this without google app scripts. If the line is bothering you I like to do View->Show->Turn Off Gridlines